# Java Mail API: Accessing "All Mail" folder of GMAIL mailbox

Tags: java, email, gmail-imap

Through Java Mail API I am able to access INBOX folder but not able to access 'All MAil' folder. I tried with many different names like 'ALLMAIL', 'ALL_MAIL' and many more but every time getting folder not found exception.

```
SessionWraper  session  = new SessionWraper();
session.openSession("imaps");
Folder inbox = session.getFolder("imap.gmail.com", "*****@gmail.com", "Password", "INBOX", Folder.READ_WRITE);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is the `[Gmail]` folder which belongs to the root folder. For example:

```
final Folder folder = store.getDefaultFolder()
    .getFolder("[Gmail]")
    .getFolder("All Mail");
final int messageCount = folder.getMessageCount();
```

or at one call:

```
final Folder folder = store.getDefaultFolder()
    .getFolder("[Gmail]/All Mail");
```

Note that the `Folder.list()` method can be used to list the folders to view and understand a folder structure.