# Archiving a message in JavaMail IMAP or GIMAP

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap, gmail-imap

I want to archive a message on a google imap account in JavaMail.

When I implement it the way I assume it should work (get the message and remove the INBOX tag via GmailFolder.setLabels()), I get an exception:

```
com.sun.mail.iap.BadCommandException: A11 BAD Invalid Arguments: Label name is not allowed: INBOX
```

This sort of makes sense because GmailMessage.getLabels() shows the absence of INBOX.

So I'm left wondering, is there a way to effectively archive a message on a gmail account using IMAP? I'm open to either using plain JavaMail IMAP or gimap classes like GmailFolder or GmailMessage. Basically I want the message removed out of the inbox but preserved in any other labels.

Comment: I think just deleting it from the INBOX should do that.  (Add \Deleted, Expunge).  This is not the same as moving it to trash.

Comment: Or if you want to do it more explicitly, [move the messages](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder.html#moveMessages-javax.mail.Message:A-javax.mail.Folder-) to the archive mailbox or wherever. Gmail will adjust tags and things.

Comment: @arnt what mailbox would I move it to for gmail? Aren't archived mails in no label?

Comment: If you only need English, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39811273/857727) will do. There's a way that works for all languages but I don't remember the javamail incantation right now. Sorry.

Comment: thanks @arnt .. that worked well.